# Multiline helm values to yaml generation issues

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a helm chart with ingress kind object.
In the ingress kind I want to allow custom annotations to be loaded from values file.
my ingress kind looks like:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: "bla"
  {{- if .Values.routing.annotations }}
  annotations:
    {{ toYaml .Values.routing.annotations | indent 4 }}
  {{- end }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "name" . }}
    chart: {{ template "chart" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
spec:
  {{- if .Values.routing.tls_enabled }}
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - {{ .Values.routing.host }}
      secretName: {{ .Values.routing.tls_secretName }}
  {{- end }}
  rules:
    - host: {{ .Values.routing.host }}
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /{{ .Values.routing.path }}
            backend:
              serviceName: service-{{ .Values.app.name }}-{{ .Values.app.CustomerName }}
              servicePort: {{ .Values.service.port }}
{{- end }}
```

**My Values.yaml file looks like:**

```
  enabled: yes
  # Note: For OpenShift change the type to route
  type: ingress
  annotations: |-
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "route"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "172800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "172800"
  # Recommendation: Set the host to {model type}-{container version}.{rest of the DNS name}
  # Note: You must update the hostname in the relevant DNS service to match the value set for the host variable
  host: localhost
  path:
  tls_enabled: no
  # For OpenShift the value of the tls_secretName variable is ignored because TLS is handled differently
  tls_secretName: chart-example.voicelab.local
```

When I want to test how helm generates the yaml file I run the command:

```
helm template .
```

it then generates the kind object with:

```
# Source: rcm/templates/ingress.yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: "bla"
  annotations:
        |-
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "route"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "172800"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "172800"

  labels:
....
```

How can I remove the '|-' ? why is it generated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this in your `values.yaml`

```
routing:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "route"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "172800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "172800"
```

then you can refer to is as to map

```
  annotations:
    {{- range $key, $value := .Values.routing.annotations }}
    {{ $key }}: {{ $value | quote }}
    {{- end }}
```

Comment: If I have removed the |- it has wrong indentation to the lines after the first line. seems like it won't recognise it is a list.

Comment: your other suggestion worked perfectly  :) if you fix the removal suggestion I'll approve your answer. since it didn't worked for me the first part.